# Format - Expected Array

Tags: vba, ms-access

I keep getting an error when I try to format this number. I've done it in VBA before and I tried to change the SOPID to a variant, a string, and an integer.

```
Dim SOPID As Integer
SOPID = DMax("file_id", "tblSOP") + 1

'Output test data
MsgBox (format(SOPID, "000"))
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You shouldn't have parentheses in your msgbox call: `MsgBox format(SOPID, "000")`. However, that's not supposed to cause this error afaik

Comment: Yea, I tried removing the parentheses just to try...it didn't fix it. Still getting the same error.

Comment: What does `DMax("file_id", "tblSOP")` return? Use a `debug.print` to find out before setting `SOPID`

Comment: Debug.Print (DMax("file_id", "tblSOP")) returned 11

Comment: Just put the cursor into `format` and press Shift+F2 to see what is being called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the code was pasted directly from your IDE, the casing of `format` is suspicious; that would be `Format`, unless there's a `format` variable or function that's in-scope, ...and that's being invoked here.

Look for a public (could be *implicitly* `Public`, or if it's in the same module then it could also be `Private`) `format` function procedure that expects an array argument: that's very likely what's being invoked here.

[Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com) (free, open-source; I manage this project) can help you easily identify exactly what's being invoked and an inspection would tell you about any [shadowed declarations](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ShadowedDeclaration), but to be sure you can fully-qualify the function call to avoid inadvertently invoking another function that's in scope:

```
MsgBox VBA.Strings.Format$(SOPID, "000")
```

Note that there are no parentheses around the argument list of a parameterized procedure call in VBA; the parentheses you have there are surrounding *the first argument* and making the expression be evaluated as a value that is then passed to the invoked function: this isn't necessary.

Also note the `$`: the `VBA.Strings.Format` function takes and returns a `Variant`; `VBA.Strings.Format$` takes and returns a `String`. If you aren't dealing with any `Null` values (an `Integer` couldn't be `Null`), consider using the `String`-returning alias.

Comment: VBA.Strings.format did the job. The VBE keeps changing Format to format though. Not sure why that is..